# Can I load a fixture with the DateField set to null?

Tags: django, django-models, django-fixtures

I'm have some Datefields I would like to keep null or blank when I load a fixture. Is there a way to keep them null or blank without putting some default value? In the model, I have already set null=True, blank=True.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
day=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

and avoid passing `auto_now_add=True` argument.